# How to move a car around an environment with hills in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, opengl, 3d

I don't have any code for this since I don't know how I am meant to do this.

I have a car and I am able to move it around on a flat plane and I have that working correctly. However, I want it to also be able to move up hills accurately. So that when I drive up a hill the front wheels start going up first and then the back wheels follow like a normal car would. So far all I have managed to be able to do is when one point of the car reaches an incline the whole car moves to that new y value instead of just the section of the car that is supposed to. Does it require some kind of translation and rotation applying to it so that it reacts correctly?

Comment: When you go up a hill, does your car rotate?  To do this realistically you will need to calculate separate positions of the front and rear tires and draw the car according to those positions.

Comment: it rotates about the axis when I use the arrow keys. Like when I press forward it moves forward and when I press left it turns left. Is there a simple kind of way to look at the bottom of the 4 wheels and the car then translate itself so that all 4 wheels stay touching the ground when they would be at different heights?

Comment: It's simple to some, not as simple to others.  If you can do basic geometric calculations and understand the GL transformation matrix, it's simple.

Comment: I have managed to do it so that the car moves forward in the direction it's facing is that some kind of start to understanding it? Would it be a rotation of the car with respect to the height of the incline that it is on?

Comment: In an arbitrary landscape, the position of the car is fixed when there are three wheels on the ground. So you cannot guarantee or expect that the is the fourth wheel is on the ground, too (at least, when the four wheels have a fixed position relative to your car object and you model does not contain something like dampers).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep track of the position of the front and rear of the car separately based on the terrain under the car.  Then calculate the transformation matrix directly from the position of the center front and center rear of the car.  Compute orthonormal vectors where one is aligned with the direction of the car, a second is horizontal, and the third is the cross product of the others.  These vectors will form the GL transformation matrix.

Calculating rotation and pitch angles is an unnecessary excursion into spherical coordinates.

It may be even simpler to use a physics library.

Comment: I still don't understand fully. What are orthonormal vectors and how do I calculate them so that they will become a transformation matrix so the car can move across the bumpy terrain?

Comment: You will also need to check if the plane of the bottom of the car is intersecting the hill.  A car which drives into the center of a cone a 5 foot tall cone with a 1 foot diameter will crash, rather than climbing it.

Comment: @user1324894: I'm afraid in that case you will need to do some reading on 3D graphics.  Or find a library that is higher-level than GL.

Comment: @Brian: physically that's true, but collision detection may not be needed.